# middleware not working in laravel 9 controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

Simple code for test

need to run middleware in the controller and its not working
also if change the middleware key with a random key its like ignore it and echo just echo the 'construct' string

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RootController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('middleware.key');
        echo 'construct<br>';
    }

   public  function test(){

            return 'test';
   }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestMiddleware extends Controller
{   
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo 'middleware';
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

```
output is :

construct
test
```

Comment: Did you register middleware in kernel? Did u try to use middleware by FQDN?

Comment: Yes i registered it and can use it in route، i wast 4 days with this problem and still broken idk why.

Comment: can you show part of Kernel.php file and your routes? because I copied your code in the project and get:construct middlewaretest

Comment: protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'test' => \App\Http\Middleware\TestMiddleware::class,
    ];

Answer (score 0):

you have to register the middleware from the `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add the middleware to your route.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Comment: i know that i should add the class and the key to kernal , i can use it already in route but cant in controller